# Virtual File System for iOS

Tags: ios, filesystems, virtual

I was wondering if one can make a virtual file system for iOS. I am trying to make a mobile version of a userspace filesystem like macfuse for Mac OS. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

I am interested in making something like dropbox where you don't actually store the files locally. I want to obtain files from dropbox and display it to user. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you interested in mounting devices, network shares, files as devices, etc? Mounting itself is not a goal, but a step to achieve something else. Since your app is sandboxed, no other app would be able to access files in your mount, so what are you trying to achieve? Is there a particular type of file that your app supports (such as Images) that is what you want?

Comment: @Neal I am interested in making something like dropbox where you don't actually store the files locally. I want to obtain files from dropbox and display it to user. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to actually mount a new file system. Fortunately, that is not necessary for your app to use the "Open With" menu to provide data to other apps.

When your app passed a file to another app, the file is copied into the target app's Inbox directory. This means it doesn't matter where the file was originally, or how it was accessed.

The simplest mechanism to access files would be to implement a custom subclass of `NSURLProtocol` for each filesystem you want to mount. If you implement it correctly, all the remaining operations should be handled for you.

Comment: So would reading up on `NSURLProtocol` help me accomplish my task of obtaining files from dropbox and displaying it to the user?

Comment: If you want to literally use Dropbox, there is already a [SDK for that](https://www.dropbox.com/developers).

Comment: I want to imitate it but allow for future expansion.

Comment: Yes. You should learn how to use NSURLProtocol.